# Cannot call replace() on a dataclass with InitVar

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Defining the following subclass:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, replace, field, InitVar

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    foo: InitVar[str]
    bar: str
    foo_len: int = field(init=False)
    def __post_init__(self, foo: int):
        self.foo_len = len(foo)
```

And creating an instance of it:

```py
instance = MyDataClass(foo="foo", bar="bar")
```

Trying to call `replace` on the instance fails:

```py
In[5]: replace(instance, bar="baz")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/or/.venv/m/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-5de186c91dc9>", line 1, in <module>
    replace(instance, bar="baz")
  File "/home/or/.venv/m/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataclasses.py", line 1170, in replace
    changes[f.name] = getattr(obj, f.name)
AttributeError: 'MyDataClass' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

As far as I understand, `InitVar`s should exist during init only, but from some investigation, I can see they are put into `__dataclass_fields__` and therefore `replace` is trying to use them.

I'm using Python 3.6, so my `dataclasses` package is the backport, not the built-in package for Python 3.7+.

I found this line in dataclasses' documentation:

> Init-only variables without default values, if any exist, must be
> specified on the call to replace() so that they can be passed to
> **init**() and **post_init**().

which means if I had the original value of `instance.foo`, I could theoretically do:

```py
replace(instance, bar="baz", foo="value of foo")
```

But I don't have the original value of `instance.foo`.

How can I avoid this error if I want to create a copy of an existing instance of a dataclass?

Comment: there is no way to avoid this error. `__post_init__` can run arbitrary code with your InitVar, and there is no way to guess it given the other attributes on your dataclass. An InitVar doesn't even need to influence your dataclass' state, maybe it just causes a side-effect like create a file with its name. How would you reproduce that behavior without knowing its value? It is conceptually impossible to copy-construct or replace a dataclass instance without explicitly passing all InitVars, too.

Comment: I don't want to reproduce this behavior. I just want a copy of the existing object with the existing values.

Comment: I see, seems I skipped over your very last sentence. If all you want is a copy, the problem is very solvable.

Answer (score 1):

Having `InitVar`s in your dataclass means that you can't call the constructor without explicitly passing the `InitVar` again. This disqualifies the usage of both `replace(instance, ...)` as well as `MyDataClass(**asdict(instance), ...)` if you don't have access to the `InitVar` any more.

If all you care about is getting a valid copy you can use the standard-librarie's `copy.copy` though, (or `copy.deepcopy` for dataclasses that have their own containers, or are otherwise nested) which does not call the instance's constructor:

```py
>>> from copy import copy
>>> instance_a = MyDataClass(foo="foo", bar="bar")
>>> instance_b = copy(instance_a)
>>> instance_b
MyDataClass(bar='bar', foo_len=3)
>>> instance_a is instance_b
False
```